# Data content of sqlite on iOS simulator not appears on DB Browser for SQLite

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, sqlite-browser

I used CoreData to create a database and I did save some content. If I navigate to local at database on iOS simulator, I can see the data using

```
select * from ZPRODUCT;
```

but, if I open with DB Browser SQLite, or other software for this, I can't see the data!

[image]

I copied the database file to desktop to make easy.

Comment: Did you copy the journal files too?

Comment: Yes, that was it, but when I close the DB Browser, the files are excluded. And I need recopy. But works fine!

Comment: How did you solve it?